# Can you multiply two separate dictionaries of different lengths together to create a third?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is it possible two multiply two separate dictionaries to update the the first / create a third?

Something like...

```
d1 = {'apples':2, 'oranges':3, 'bananas':4}
d2 = {'apples':4, 'oranges':6, 'bananas':8, 'pears':10}
update_d1 = {}

for i in d1:
    update_d1[i] = d1[i] * d2[i]

print(update_d1)
```

Comment: `if (i in d1) and (i in d2):`. What is wrong with the code you have provided?

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is using a dict comprehension over the union of the sets of keys, using `get` with a default of 1 for the multiplication:

```py
>>> { k: d1.get(k, 1) * d2.get(k, 1) for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys() }
{'pears': 10, 'bananas': 32, 'oranges': 18, 'apples': 8}
```

Comment: The defaults can be set to 0 if we don't want the key to be present in final dictionary if not present in both dictionaries.

Comment: If you want only keys present in both dictionaries, use the intersection: `{ k: d1[k] * d2[k] for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys() }`. Using a default of 0 would make those keys present with a value of 0.

Answer (score 3):

How about a `defaultdict` solution? This updates one of the dictionaries in-place.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = defaultdict(lambda : 1, d1)
for k in d2:
    d1[k] *= d2[k]
```

```
dict(d1)
# {'apples': 8, 'bananas': 32, 'oranges': 18, 'pears': 10}
```

Comment: I like this solution, +1. As a certified nitpicker I have to point out that this isn't technically in-place, since it does create a new data structure and the changes aren't visible via other references to the original dictionary.

Comment: @kaya3 Sure! the `defaultdict(lambda : 1, d1)` can be reassigned to something different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pandas one liner:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(d1,[0]),pd.DataFrame(d2,[0]), 'outer').fillna(1).astype(int).groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).cumprod().drop(0).to_dict(orient='records')[0]  

# {'apples': 8, 'oranges': 18, 'bananas': 32, 'pears': 10}
```